# How is remote debugging over 1394 cable working?

Tags: windbg, remote-debugging

I'm a bit confused by the MSDN documentation.

There are two articles that I don't fully understand.
First http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh451173(v=vs.85).aspx that says:

> Suppose you are set up to establish a kernel-mode debugging session,
>   between a host computer and a target computer, over a 1394 cable on
>   channel 32. You can use the following procedure to establish a remote
>   debugging session: 
>   On the host computer, enter the following command
>   in a Command Prompt window. **windbg -server tcp:port=5005 -k
>   1394:channel=32** On the remote computer, enter the following command in
>   a Command Prompt window. **windbg -remote
>   tcp:Port=5005,Server=YourHostComputer** where YourHostComputer is the
>   name of your host computer, which is running the debugging server.

If this is done over a 1394 cable, why does the command say "tcp:port=5005" ?

I managed to set up a connection using the above instructions, but I don't understand exactly what the command does.

Second, this seems to do a totally different thing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556866(v=vs.85).aspx

I need some "for beginners" type of info. Some words about how this works or some documentations that explains things a bit more in detail will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `windbg -server tcp:port=5005 -k 1394:channel=32` opens up two connections:

1. FireWire connection on channel #32 to the kernel debugger on a *target* machine.
2. Starts listening on TCP port 5005, so that somebody else could connect from other (remote) machine.

You don't have to have a connection #2 if you have access to desktop on host machine. In such cases you can simply remove `-server ...` option from command line.

Comment: So windbg -k 1394:channel=<ChannelNumber> on host machine, but how do I connect the target? windbg -remote tcp:Port=5005,Server=YourHostComputer is clearly connecting it via the tcp port.

Comment: Connection #1 is what connects host machine to target machine. You only need connection #2 is you don't have access to desktop of the host machine.